# cookies not persisting when using dockerized nginx as a proxy to multiple backend docker containers

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, cookies, reverse-proxy

I have two separate apps - one in python, one in go - both in their own separate docker images. Together these two apps make one website - they need to share session data (cookies) between each other. This works just fine the way it is now (go app on one host, python app on another, nginx on a third proxying to each).

What I want to do is run them both on the same host, using an nginx docker container as a proxy between the two (consolidation purposes). So I have a docker-compose file ([Dockerrun.aws.json](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_v2config.html#create_deploy_docker_v2config_dockerrun) when deploying to AWS) setup with nginx, linked to the two images and configured to proxy to each.

I have the proxy working as intended - different routes go to different backends - no issues there. The only problem is, cookies do not persist.

The python app is responsible for logging users in - stores data in a cookie. The go app should be able to read this cookie to get the data it needs. However, the cookie doesn't persist, so I can't log in to either app. I don't think the cookie is making it's way to the browser.

Doing some research, I thought setting [`proxy_cookie_domain`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cookie_domain) would work. My thought was, as long as cookies are being set under the same host/domain, they should be accessible in both apps.

Any ideas? I can't be the only one doing this.
FYI - I'm using the official [nginx docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/) - only thing different is the site config.

```
site.nginx.conf
---------------

proxy_cookie_domain python $host;
proxy_cookie_domain go $host;
proxy_set_header    Host $host;

server {
    listen      80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://go:3000;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://python:5000;
    }
}



docker-compose.yml
------------------

version: "2"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    links:
      - python
      - go
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always

  python:
    image: python-image
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    restart: always

  go:
    image: go-image
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    restart: always



Dockerrun.aws.json
------------------

{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion":2,
    "containerDefinitions":[
        {
            "name":"nginx",
            "image":"nginx",
            "essential":true,
            "memoryReservation":128,
            "links":[
                "python",
                "go"
            ],
            "portMappings":[
                {
                    "hostPort":80,
                    "containerPort":80
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name":"python",
            "image":"python-image",
            "essential":true,
            "memoryReservation":128,
            "portMappings":[
                {
                    "hostPort":5000,
                    "containerPort":5000
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name":"go",
            "image":"go-image",
            "essential":true,
            "memoryReservation":128,
            "portMappings":[
                {
                    "hostPort":3000,
                    "containerPort":3000
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**UPDATE**

Using chrome developer tools, I can see that the request headers are being sent to the server as expected (`Cookie` header present and looks like what i'd expect). I can also see that the `Set-Cookie` header is being sent after a successful login, as expected.

I can log in to the site through the python  app. I can even switch from one python page to another with no problem. But once I try to switch over to a go page, I am no longer logged in. And further, when I try to go back to a python page, I'm not logged in anymore. The cookies are sent in every request.

The reason this is all confusing to me is because when I run everything in it's own container, running on it's own host (proxied by a separate host running nginx), everything runs as expected. And it's the same exact code, so it's not like the code is destroying the cookie object.

Comment: When you say cookies don't persist, do you mean that cookies set in request and response headers are not being passed through by the proxy?

Comment: @rahoogan added updates to the question

Comment: It sounds like your apps might be using the local filesystem to persist session data. This will not be accessible between containers unless you use a Docker volume.

Comment: turned out to be a config issue... not related to docker at all

Comment: @BDuelz, what was the config issue?